# Convert date strings in an array to datetime objects

Tags: php, arrays, datetime

how can I loop through an array and convert all date field to a date object?

I have an array;

```
array (size=37)
  'id' => string '12' (length=3)
  'name' => string 'Jack' (length=6)
  'surname' => string 'Smith' (length=1)
  'age' => string '24' (length=1)
  'birthdate' => string '19920512' (length=0)
  'joindate' => string '20160923' (length=0)
  'graduationdate' => string '' (length=0)
```

I want to convert the date strings to date time object like this;

```
$record['birthdate'] = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $record['birthdate']);
```

But I want to automatically detect the date keys, and make the value a datetime object, if the value is an empty string it can just make it false.

I'm a bit confused

```
foreach ($record as $value) {
    $value = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $value['xxx']);
}
```

Comment: You can loop on every properties of the array and check the value with a regex. If it matches, (implying it's not empty!) then you have a date string that you can convert using the DateTime class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach($array as $key => &$field){
    if(strpos($key,'date')!==false && strlen($field)==10 AND is_numeric($field)){
        $field = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Ymd', $field);
    }
}
print_r($array);
```

Why in this way:

- We iterate over all `key=values` pairs with a foreach
- We check the `key` for the word-part `date` to detected datefields
- Then we check for a useable numbers with 10 digits
- If all is ok, we make an object from the value
- And because of the use of `&` in the foreach, we change the value directly in the array.

Have nice day

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @JohnConde OK, added some infos.

Comment: Great answer. I already have that loop to convert number strings to integers and floats, and convert empty strings to null values, I can just add the if  for the dates part. I never thought of `strpos`

Comment: Beat me to it, nevertheless, strpos($key,'date') works (great) only on this given example becouse it searches string position inside a key.

Answer (score -1):

You can use `strtotime()` http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php to convert a string containing a date.

```
<?php
// both lines output 813470400
echo strtotime("19951012"), "\n",
     strtotime("12 October 1995");
?>
```

You can pass the result as the second parameter to date() to reformat the date yourself:

```
<?php
// prints 1995 Oct 12
echo date("Y M d", strtotime("19951012"));
?>
```